# Working QSignalMapper code is clumsy to read

Tags: qt, qt5, qsignalmapper

I read the documentation of `QSignalMapper` and I've ended up with this code:

```
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOn1, 1);
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOn2, 2);
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOn3, 3);
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOn4, 4);
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOn5, 5);
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOn6, 6);
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOn7, 7);
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOn8, 8);
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOnAll, -1);

connect(ui->btnRelayOn1, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(ui->btnRelayOn2, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(ui->btnRelayOn3, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(ui->btnRelayOn4, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(ui->btnRelayOn5, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(ui->btnRelayOn6, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(ui->btnRelayOn7, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(ui->btnRelayOn8, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(ui->btnRelayOnAll, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, static_cast<void (QSignalMapper::*)()>(&QSignalMapper::map));
connect(&_mapperOn, &QSignalMapper::mappedInt, this, &FormMonitor::setRelayOn);
```

In my form I have 8 `QPushButton`s and I mapped them to my `QSignalMapper` in order to connect all of them to the same slot passing an index.

**It works.** But I don't like the code at all! It's not much different than connect each button to its own slot... I hope I misunderstood the docs and there's a better way to avoid this clumsy code. My actual form contains several of this kind of setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need many widgets that work as a group you can create composite widget, encapsulate mapping in it and provide public interface (signals) as something more managable.

Or you can create buttons dynamically like in [calculator](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/examples/widgets/widgets/calculator/calculator.cpp) qt example.

At least you can put buttons in `QList` and connect and map them in a loop.

```cpp
QSignalMapper _mapperOn;

QList<QPushButton*> buttons = {
    ui->btnRelayOn1,
    ui->btnRelayOn2,
    ui->btnRelayOn3,
    ui->btnRelayOn4,
    ui->btnRelayOn5,
    ui->btnRelayOn6,
    ui->btnRelayOn7,
    ui->btnRelayOn8
};

for(int i=0;i<buttons.size();i++) {
    _mapperOn.setMapping(buttons[i], i);
    connect(buttons[i], &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, &QSignalMapper::map);
}
_mapperOn.setMapping(ui->btnRelayOnAll, -1);
connect(ui->btnRelayOnAll, &QPushButton::clicked, &_mapperOn, &QSignalMapper::map);

connect(&_mapperOn, &QSignalMapper::mappedInt, this, &FormMonitor::setRelayOn);
```